# Issue with scraping JS rendered page with Scrapy and Splash

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm trying to scrape [this page](https://www.phillips.com/detail/BRIDGET-RILEY/UK010417/19) which includes following html according to chrome

```
<p class="title">

            Orange Paired

        </p>
```

this is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "splash"
    allowed_domains = ["phillips.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.phillips.com/detail/BRIDGET-RILEY/UK010417/19"]
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url,
                self.parse,
                endpoint='render.json',
                args={'har': 1, 'html': 1}
            )
    def parse(self, response):
        print("1. PARSED", response.real_url, response.url)
        print("2. ",response.css("title").extract())
        print("3. ",response.data["har"]["log"]["pages"])
        print("4. ",response.headers.get('Content-Type'))
        print("5. ",response.xpath('//p[@class="title"]/text()').extract())
```

This is the output of `scrapy runspider spiders/splash_spider.py`

```
2017-08-31 09:48:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
1. PARSED http://localhost:8050/render.json https://www.phillips.com/detail/BRIDGET-RILEY/UK010417/19
2.  ['<title>PHILLIPS : Bridget Riley, Orange Paired</title>', '<title>Page 1</title>']
3.  [{'title': 'PHILLIPS : Bridget Riley, Orange Paired', 'pageTimings': {'onContentLoad': 3832, '_onStarted': 1, '_onIframesRendered': 4667, 'onLoad': 4664, '_onPrepareStart': 4664}, 'id': '1', 'startedDateTime': '2017-08-31T07:48:18.986240Z'}]
4.  b'text/html; charset=utf-8'
5.  []
2017-08-31 09:48:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Why am I getting an empty output for 5?

What I also don't understand is that Splash doesn't seem to render the page linked above
[image]

but it renders the top level homepage
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good starting point in such cases is to look at [FAQ](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly) section of Splash documentation. It turns out that in your case you need to [disable Private mode](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-disable-private-mode) for Splash, either via `--disable-private-mode` startup option for Docker, or by setting `splash.private_mode_enabled = false` in your LUA script.

Once you disable Private mode, the page renders correctly.

Comment: I started Docker with  `--disable-private-mode` and it worked. Thank you very much