# Scrapy + Splash Rendering a JavaScript data

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrap a ecommerce site using **scrapy** and **splash**, as most of the content on the page is dynamic which is rendered by **JS**, I am using splash to fetch the data. I am able to fetch all the other data except the price data.

```
<div class="grid-row rendered">
    <span data-id="from-price" data-bind="visible: showFromLabel, text: fromLabelText, css: { 'price-from-discounted' : isDiscountedPrice }" class="price-from" style="display: none;">From</span>
    <span data-id="current-price" data-bind="text: priceText(), css: {'product-price-discounted' : isDiscountedPrice }" class="current-price">$31.58</span>
    <span data-id="rrp-price" data-bind="text: rrpPriceText, visible: showRrpPrice" class="product-prev-price" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span data-id="previous-price" data-bind="text: prevPriceText, visible: showPrevPrice" class="product-prev-price" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span data-id="german-vat-message" data-bind="text: germanVatMessage, visible: showGermanVatMessage" class="product-german-vat" style="display: none;"></span>
</div>
```

I want to fetch the 2nd span data, but the `div.grid-row` rendered is not rendered when I `print(response.body)`.

How can I get that price data.

Here is the link to the [page](http://www.asos.com/asos/asos-oversized-longline-short-sleeve-hoodie/prd/8409775?clr=white&SearchQuery=&cid=5668&pgesize=204&pge=0&totalstyles=2196&gridsize=3&gridrow=1&gridcolumn=1)

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the problem, I ran the web page inside scrapy shell with splash and then when I did `view(response)`, it turned out that the price section was not loaded, then I googled around and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976331/issue-with-scraping-js-rendered-page-with-scrapy-and-splash),
Basically, I just had to run the splash in private mode as per shown in the answer from the link.